# Retaining filenames while processing files in Apache Beam

Tags: java, apache-beam, avro

I'm writing an app in Apache Beam that builds a catalog of file contents as files are added to storage.  It operates on an unbounded stream of filenames.  This is easy enough to pipe to `FileIO.matchAll` -> `FileIO.readMatches` -> `AvroIO.readFilesGenericRecords`; however, I'd like to retain the original filename with each Avro record decoded and it seems there are the following issues that complicate matters:

1. The origin filename is not stored as part of Avro decoding.
2. There is an implicit flatten with `AvroIO.readFilesGenericRecords` that produces an undifferentiated `PCollection` of records.
3. While I can map the file matches to `PCollection<KV<String,MatchResult$Metadata>>` to preserve the filename, this can't be directly be operated on by the `AvroIO` transforms.

What sort of design options are open here?  Is there a way to have a `KV` mapping that can still be operated on by `AvroIO` or would I have to write my own decoding from scratch?

Comment: frankly this is silly and frustrating. I think the only option I can think is to create a feature request for Beam to add this capability... let me know if you'd like help adfding the feature request...

Comment: I did come about a workaround that involved creating a new subclass of `FileBasedSource<KV<ResourceId,T>>` that contains an instance of `AvroSource` that it can farm out most of the work to.  It's hard to reason about, though, and likely prone to future breakage, so I may take you up on that offer to push a feature request.